# И кот(,) и собака(,) и рысь

Tags: запятые

Если следовать тому, что написано в РАН – http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112, – то делается вывод, что в таких примерах не надо никаких вообще-таки запятых, как те, написанные внизу.

1. У меня был и кот и пёс.
2. Я ем и грибы и ягоды.
3. У Леопольда и друг и подружка есть.

А если же есть опять повторяющийся союз *и*, у которого нет обобщающего слова и слова которого не имею определений, но этого союза, например, не два, а три – или более – или если там есть три слова, но два союза *и*?

1. У меня есть и кот(,) и собака(,) и рысь.
2. Дерево(,) и куст(,) и роза являются прекрасными.
3. И днём(,) и ночью(,) и вечером он пишет – и только пишет.
4. Днём(,) и ночью(,) и вечером он пишет – и только пишет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. [ПРАВИЛО РОЗЕНТАЛЯ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)**

У Розенталя это тема повторяющихся союзов, там материал дан в более понятной форме.

**Пункт 2**. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется **тесное смысловое единство** (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе **пояснительных** слов): Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.);

Такие смысловые единства образуются словами с **ассоциативными** (часто антонимическими) связями: и друзья и враги, и зимой и летом, и любовь и ненависть, и музыка и пение, и радость и горе, и стихи и проза, и тело и душа

**Пункт 3.** При наличии пояснительных слов при одном из двух однородных членов предложения между ними **ставится** запятая: Срубленные осины придавили собой и траву, и мелкий кустарник (Т.); Всё вокруг переменилось: и природами характер леса (Л. Т.).

**Пункт 4.** Внутри выражений **фразеологического** характера с повторяющимися союзами и…и, ни…ни запятая не ставится: и день и ночь. и смех и горе. и стар и млад,и туда и сюда.  Ср. в пословицах и поговорках: Ни Богу свечка, ни чёрту кочерга; Ни в городе Богдан, ни в селе Селифан.

**Вывод из правила.**  Тесное единство  возможно только **для двух** однородных членов. Тогда запятая не ставится, нет перечисления, а повторяющийся союз И…И фактически приравнивается **к одиночному союзу** И. При этом первый союз И используется в качестве усилительной частицы.

Однако такое единство **неустойчиво** и проявляется при **конкретных** условиях. К примеру, **пояснительные** слова нарушают единство. Это касается и **фразеологизмов**, которые чаще применяются в значении единства, но не всегда.

**2. ГРАММАТИКА**  (сравнение одиночного союза И и повторяющегося союз И…И)

[Русская корпусная грамматика. Сочинительные союзы](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#21)

**Повторяющиеся союзы**

Повторяющиеся союзы имеют общие семантические и синтаксические особенности.  Для понимания этих особенностей важно **отличать** повторяющийся союз от формально похожей единицы – повторенного одиночного союза. По сравнению с одиночными, повторяющиеся союзы имеют **два общих семантических свойства**

**Свойство (1):** каждый член предложения участвует в сочинении. Свойство (1) означает: повторяющийся союз **подчеркивает**, что семантическое отношение, им выражаемое, затрагивает **все без исключения** члены. В предложении с одиночным союзом тоже, конечно, все члены участвуют в сочинении, однако этот смысл **не подчеркнут**; его подчеркивание как раз и составляет семантическую **специфику** повторяющегося союза.

Свойство (2): каждый член предложения рассматривается **отдельно.** Свойство (2) означает, что в предложении с повторяющимся союзом предикат соотносится с каждым из членов по отдельности.

Из грамматики можно сделать **ВЫВОД**: при тесном смысловом единстве мы рассматриваем союз И...И как **одиночный** союз И, но не как повторяющийся союз. При использовании союза И...И каждый член предложения будет самостоятельным, то есть единства **не будет.** И в  каждом конкретном случае мы или обозначаем это  **смысловое единство**, или, напротив, подчеркиваем **самостоятельность** однородных членов.

**3. РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

**Группа 1. Два однородных члена**

**Пример 1.**

*— У тебя были животные, например  кот или пес? —  **У меня был и кот, и пёс.***

— У тебя есть какие-нибудь  животные, например  кот или пес? — У меня были  **и кот и пес,** но сейчас нет никого.

**Пояснение.** Говорящий предложил  выбор, а в ответе **подчеркивается,** что было  **каждое** из названных животных. Говорящий опять предложил  выбор, а в ответе говорится, что **оба животных**  были раньше,  а теперь вот нет никого.

**Пример 2.**

*— Ты ешь грибы или ягоды? — Что за странный вопрос? **Я ем и грибы, и ягоды.***

— *Ты ешь что-нибудь из «лесных даров», грибы или ягоды? — Я ем **и грибы и ягоды,** только вот в лес хожу редко.*

**Пример 3.**

— У твоего кота Леопольда есть друг или подружка? — У Леопольда **и друг, и подружка** есть, кого у него только нет.

— У твоего кота Леопольда есть друг или подружка? — У Леопольда **и друг и подружка** есть, но гуляет он  редко.

**Группа 1. Три однородных члена**

**[У Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)**

Пункт 1. Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимися союзами и…и, да…да, ни…ни, или…или, либо…либо, то…то, не то…не то и др., ставится запятая.

Пункт 6. Если однородных членов предложения **более двух**, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, **кроме первого**, то запятая ставится между всеми однородными членами.

Пункт 7. Между всеми однородными членами предложения запятая ставится также в том случае, когда только **часть** их связана повторяющимися союзами, а остальные соединяются бессоюзной связью:

Таким образом, запятые ставятся **во всех примерах:**

*У меня есть и кот, и собака, и рысь. Дерево, и куст, и роза являются прекрасными. И днём, и ночью, и вечером он пишет – и только пишет. Днём, и ночью, и вечером он пишет – и только пишет.*

**Исключение** возможно в частных случаях, если два члена **выделены** из группы:

*У меня есть **и кот и собака**, и даже рысь.  **И днём и ночью**, и также вечером он пишет – и только пишет.*

Comment: Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.) в этом предложении есть предикация, то есть "кругом"-было и прекрасно(светло и зелено). Кругом и прекрасно - и соединяет однородные наречия. С котами мне кажется сложнее, там не ясна предикация, ну были и были, приходится в дополнительном контексте искать условие. Насколько это честно, переносить условие из предыдущего предложения на данное?

Comment: Кругом было и светло и зелено.  Да, здесь тесное единство, и это можно определить по формальному признаку "кругом". Но тесное единство возможно и в других предложениях, в том числе оно может определяться для конкретного предложения по семантическим признакам. Так что ничего нечестно не переносится, а используется своё.

Comment: В моем понимании признак - это либо очевидное обобщающее слово, либо идиоматическое вроде "отец и мать" = родители. А вот "друг и подружка" - это что такое, как их можно соединить? Друзья и подружки - еще ладно, но это не в единственном числе.

Comment: Ну вот вы сами невольно добавляете предикации: У меня есть и кот и собака, и **даже** рысь. Потому что без неё фраза разваливается. То есть в разговорной речи добавить акцент можно, но в письменной это уже непонятно.

Comment: Формальным признаком я назвала общее наречие "кругом". Здесь оно явно объединяет сказуемые. В предложении с рысью последнийИ присоединительный, он не "участвует" в тесном единстве.

Comment: А я считаю объединяются именно предикация и обобщение(которая тоже суть предикация). То есть кругом и "светло-и-зелено". В противном случае глагол хочется сместить в конец, потому что это нетипичная постановка фразы, которая за счет этого может дать нужную интонацию и как раз будет этой негласной предикацией: и светло и зелено было.

Comment: Пусть себе объединяются. У меня другая причина для объединения,  а именно семантика всего предложения.

Comment: То есть "светло-и-зелено" = живописно. Было кругом и живописно. Рисую кругом и рисую живописно.

Comment: Не понимаю вас. Может, лучше к котам перейдем поближе)  Вы можете написать; Кругом и светло, и зелено, и живописно, и красиво , и т.д. А можете: Кругом и светло, и зелено, всюду птички поют. Здесь автор свободен в выборе.

Comment: С котами я добавил. Дело в том, что коты - это не понятия, это просто коты. Поэтому согласование идет только по первому коту: был и кот, и пёс, был и бык, и куры. А если дальше понятие, тогда согласование будет во множественном числе - былИ. Однако, предикации нет, и фраза воспринимается с трудом. У меня - это что предикация? Не у тебя, а у меня? Ну можно, но я бы так не делал. Кроме того, у Толстого светло и зелено - это не существительные, а опять же наречия, признаки. А у меня были кошачьи и собачьи(животные). Но даже так криво. Если в конец поставить были, то еще можно.

Comment: У меня и кот и пёс, и был и куры были = у меня такие были. А, "у меня были такие!" - это совсем другая фраза, она очень экспрессивна и вряд ли её можно везде использовать, потому что "были такие кто"?

Comment: Ну ладно, будем считать,  что вам не нравится мой ответ.  Вряд ли мы сможем договориться, так как все в этой теме понимаем по-разному.  Мне правда жаль.  Мне хотелось через грамматику объяснить это правило, но, видно, не получилось)  Но это ничево, правда? )

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы добавили предикации, которых не было в оригинале: И днём и ночью, и **также** вечером он пишет. Но ничяво.

Answer (score 0):

> "Однако при отсутствии указанных условий при однородных членах
> предложения, образующих тесное смысловое единство, запятая может не
> ставиться."

Может не ставиться, если собака и кошка образуют единство. А если не образуют, то ставится.

У меня был**и** и кот и пёс. - я передумал, не нужна если были, потому что кот и пёс - животные, у меня были и животные. Хотя, лучше убрать глагол в конец: **у меня и кот и пёс были**.

У меня **был** и кот, и пёс. - тут нужна. Потому что нет связи кота и пса. При согласовании глагол согласуется по первому существительному. У меня был и кот, и куры. У меня были и коты, и курица. Если же перечисление, то ставится были и я бы ставил двоеточие - "у меня были: и кот, и пёс, и куры."

Дерево(,) и куст(,) и роза являются прекрасными. - какая-то нерусскаязычная хрень, потому что "..- являются прекрасными цветами". Либо: "...и роза - прекрасны", - Обобщающее слово прекрасны. Нужна запятая.

Я ем и грибы, и ягоды. Я ем всё: и грибы, и ягоды.

Я **ем** и грибы и ягоды... - сомнительно по интонации. Я бы поставил в конец: я и грибы и ягоды **ем**. Я и их ем - то есть.

Если всё это не обобщающие слово, а однородное дополнение, то:

Я ем всё и грибы и ягоды.( я ем всё(магазинное) и ещё лесное, я ем всё и грибы-и-ягоды - грибы и ягоды - обобщение, а первое И соединяет однородные все и "общее")

Я собираю и грибы, и ягоды. Я и грибы и ягоды **собираю**.

Либо, первое И имеет смысл заменить на "даже", тогда: я собираю даже грибы и ягоды.

У Леопольда... - тут вообще не удачное сочетание. Не ясно, что такое "друг и подружка". У Леопольда и отец и мать есть, и дед с бабкою. Мать и отец - родители. У Леопольда есть и карандаш, и ручка. У Леопольда есть: и дом, и двор, и огород.

У меня есть: и кот, и собака, и рысь. - они есть, нужна.

И днём, и ночью, и вечером он пишет – и только пишет. - названия времени суток, нужна. Выражение и днем и ночью = сутки, а не время суток.

Тоже самое.

Но

И днем и ночью он пишет, и сегодня вечером написал. - тут не нужна.

То есть:

Не все словосочетания А и Б можно обобщить, особенно, когда дело касается понятий, вроде "друг и подружка" - это как?

Если нет предикации, но есть целостная конструкция, то лучше глагол ставить в конец. Перестановка глагола в конец, в моем понимании, дает интонацию удивления и восполняет как раз нехватающую предикацию, как-то: даже, неужели и тп. В противном случае лучше вместо первого союза И использовать наречия вроде "даже, только, вроде и тд": у меня есть **даже** собака и кошка.

Согласование когда глагол и перечисление существительных далее делается по первому существительному.

У меня и **кот и пёс**, и **был и куры** были. = у меня **такие** были.

А теперь сравните: у меня были такие. - фраза очень ситуативная и связана с диалогом, возможна только при утвердительном или уточняющем ответе на вопрос: у тебя были такие? В то время как "у меня такие были" - фраза самодостаточная повествовательная и не требует дополнительного контекста.

То есть фраза: у меня били и такие - звучит как ответ "да" на вопрос, точно такой же по содержанию.

-Какие у тебя были? -Те и вот такие. -У тебя были такие? -У меня были и такие.

В то время как фраза "у меня и такие были" - повествовательная хотя с акцентом на "такие".

Comment: Я не очень понимаю вас, поэтому вам лучше  записать свое решение этой задачи, потом найти у меня ошибки и объяснить  их. Так будет проще и короче.